# Build error saying as - "Unable to load class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmCompilerOptionsHelper' "

Tags: android, kotlin, build

I have tried to migrate into the version catalog but I am not able to build the app but I am getting build error

Unable to load class **'org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmCompilerOptionsHelper'**.

This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.

```
[versions]
androidGradlePlugin = "8.1.1"
hilt = "2.48"
ksp = "1.9.0-1.0.13"

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "androidGradlePlugin" }
android-library = { id = "com.android.library", version.ref = "androidGradlePlugin" }
hilt = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = "hilt" }
ksp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = "ksp" }

build.gradle.kts(Project)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android) apply (false)
    alias(libs.plugins.hilt) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.ksp) apply false
}

build.gradle.kts(app)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) 
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android) 
    alias(libs.plugins.hilt) 
    alias(libs.plugins.ksp) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue as you and resolved it by changing the Gradle user home directory. This build error occurs when the Gradle files are corrupted. You can change the Gradle user home directory through:

```
'Settings' -> 'Build, Execution, Deployment' -> 'Build Tools' -> 'Gradle'
```

After resetting the Gradle user home directory, Gradle will re-download the necessary files to build the project. It should work fine after re-downloading and resetting the Gradle files in the user home directory.